# Ajax button php variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a ajax button to run a link with php code. In the code below when I click the button it gives a refresh on the page and does not run the line:

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.0.106:8080/v1/devices/'<?php $deviceID; ?>'/led/?access_token='<?php $dispositivo ?>'?params=l1,HIGH', success: function(result){
```

I want it to only run the line, without refreshing the entire page, where is the problem?

```
<?
echo "<form method='post' action='test.php'>";
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.0.106:8080/v1/devices/'<?php  $deviceID; ?>'/led/?access_token='<?php $dispositivo ?>'?params=l1,HIGH', success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Liga</button>
<?
     echo "</form>";//fim do formulÃ¡rio
?>
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default action, ie. e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove apostrophe (')

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.0.106:8080/v1/devices/<?php echo $deviceID; ?>/led/?access_token=<?php $dispositivo ?>?params=l1,HIGH', success: function(result){
```

or

```
$.ajax({url: 'http://192.168.0.106:8080/v1/devices/'+<?php echo $deviceID; ?>+'/led/?access_token=<?php $dispositivo ?>?params=l1,HIGH', success: function(result){
```

this string is Javascript string

```
'http://192.168.0.106:8080/v1/devices/'+<?php echo $deviceID; ?>+'/led/?access_token=<?php $dispositivo ?>?params=l1,HIGH'
```

and you must use `echo` to add php string to it.

Comment: using your code It run but don't get php variables values

Comment: the code is JavaScript, but you use it like php.